# How to generate data from this particular multivariate distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $(X_0,X_1)$ be a random vector distributed according to the CDF $F_{(X_0,X_1)}(x,y)= \min (F_{X_0}(x),F_{X_1}(y))$ where $F_{X_0}(x),F_{X_1}(x)$ are the CDFs of $X_0,X_1$ respectively. We do not necessarily have densities.

I know how to sample from a one-dimensional CDF using inverse transform sampling. I want to sample from $F_{(X_0,X_1)}$.

My idea:

Sample $x_0$ from $F_{X_0}$. Then sample $x_1$ from $F_{(X_0,X_1)}(x_0,\cdot)$ which is now univariate. Is this correct ? How to prove that $(x_0,x_1)$ is indeed sampled according to $F_{(X_0,X_1)}$ ?

EDIT: my proposal is wrong since $F_{(X_0,X_1)}(x_0,\cdot)$ is not a CDF.

Comment: If they are independent, you can just do separate inverse transforms.  If they are not independent, it is significantly harder, except in some narrow cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Big hint**: For inverse transform sampling, you use a uniform random variable $U$ to generate a sample $X=F_{X}^{-1}(U)$. What happens if you use the *same* $U$ to generate both $X_0=F_{X_0}^{-1}(U)$ and $X_1=F_{X_1}^{-1}(U)$?