# Inverse transform sampling from a bivariate distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I have a grid of points on a sphere with $\theta$, $\phi$ coordinates where every point has some value $f_i$ and $\sum_i f_i =1$. My goal is to apply inverse transform sampling: generate pairs of uniformly random numbers and for every pair of such numbers calculate values of $\theta$, $\phi$ coordinates according to the distribution $f$.

For a univariate case the problem is straightforward. For instance, if the data would be axisymmetric, one would generate a uniformly random variable $s\in [0,1]$ and compute numerically the inverse of CDF $s=F(\theta)=2\pi \int_0^\theta f(\theta') \sin(\theta')\mathrm{d}\theta'$ such as $\theta = F^{-1}(s)$. $\phi$ could be determined by generating a different uniformly random variable $t\in[0,1]$ and $\phi=t$.

How does this change in a bivariate case and why? I read several discussions with similar topics. However, the process is still not clear to me.
For instance, in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21834268/how-to-generate-random-variables-from-a-bivariate-known-pdf-in-r) it is stated that one should use marginal distribution to get the value of one variable and then the conditional probability to determine the other variable.
While in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4308275/how-to-generate-data-from-this-particular-multivariate-distribution) it is stated (in a comment to the post) that if the variables are independent, one could simply do separate inverse transforms.